# Generating tessellation in ArcGIS Desktop versions before 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tesselation

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 and want to generate a tesselation grid but this tool is available in 10.3 or versions of ArcGIS.

Is there any way I can generate a hexagon grid for my study area using ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Comment: Have you checked [Create Hexagon Tessellation](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=03388990d3274160afe240ac54763e57)?

Comment: I was generating hexagons (and triangle-filled hexagons) at Arc/Info 6.0; it's just a little trigonometry, after all.

Comment: I would say you are using an old version of ArcMap that not even ESRI really support, time you should upgrade then you will have lots of tools to choose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some experience using a tool developed by Jenness Enterprises.
I used this with ArcMap 9.3.1, looking on the site I see there is a 10.x version. Which should be able to give you what you need in 10.2.2.

http://www.jennessent.com/arcgis/repeat_shapes.htm

> Citation:
>
> Jenness, J. 2012. Repeating shapes for ArcGIS. Jenness
> Enterprises. Available at:
> http://www.jennessent.com/arcgis/repeat_shapes.htm.

Unfortunately I do not have access to ArcMap to test it, I am going on what I remember from using 9.3.1.